# jQuery selector background-image

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to identify the selector is by the spesific background-image. Is there a way to do this?

```
<ul style="background-image:url(/test/test/shortcutsMenu-test.png);">
```

I know this is not the right way to do it, but I'm manipulating a website to a mobile version of the same site.

Comment: Using a css class is much easier: `<ul class="shortcut-menu">` and `$(".shortcut-menu")`.

Comment: I know that this is not the best way to do this, but I'm manipulating a website to a mobile-site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("ul").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("background-image") === "url(/test/test/shortcutsMenu-test.png)"; 
});
```

This will allow you to select `ul` elements that have a background image defined elsewhere, not only inline. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WWuXw/1/).

If you don't care about that, and the background image will always be applied inline in a `style` attribute, you could use an "[attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)" selector with the `style` attribute.

**Update** (based on comments)

To just search for part of the file name you can use normal JavaScript string methods like `indexOf` (since the jQuery `css` method returns a string):

```
$("ul").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("background-image").indexOf("findThisString") > -1; 
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to only search after the filename, without the entire url .. like $(this).css("background-image") === "url(shortcutsMenu-test.png)";

Comment: Yes, just use `indexOf` on the value returned by `css`. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 2):

one way of doing it is:

```
$('ul[style*="/test/test/shortcutsMenu-test.png"]')
```

JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PZnuF/)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You'll presumably want the Attribute Contains Word selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/</strike>

```
$('[style~="/test/test/shortcutsMenu-test.png"]').get();
```

**Edit:** This is wrong.  The Attribute Contains selector should be used in this case, as it will match to substrings rather than whitespace-delimited words:

```
$('[style*="/test/test/shortcutsMenu-test.png"]').get();
```

Comment: It tests for _words_ (_... where a "word" is defined as a string delimited by whitespace..._) so i don't know if it will work, but i like the idea.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right.  Apparently the Attribute Contains selector should match to substrings.  http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/